# Store Objects and call those Objects one after another in an iteration cycle

Tags: python, list, object, iteration

I want to store 4 value-objects in a list and then call each of the objects in an iteration cycle, so that they are execute one after each other.

I assigned the objects to a value and stored those in a list, now to loop with the function.

```
i = 0

def printing():

    eins = print('1')
    zwei = print('2')
    drei = print('3')
    vier = print('4')

    printer=[eins, zwei, drei, vier]


    for i in printer():
        printer(i)
        i += 1

    print('next')  
printing(4)
```

Now I expect the print but something is wrong.. 
How do I call the printer list as an action, I feel that's where its wrong.

Comment: you are assigning `None` to 4 variables, since that's what `print` returns... calling `None` obviously fails. Also `printer` is a list, it's not callable... why are you adding `()` at random?

Comment: Could you please your expected output and your current output? I couldn't get the problem properly

Comment: first you are calling `printing` with `arg` while its do note take any `arg`. And then `print` return `None`. Be specific what you are trying to do with this code

Answer (score 0):

`print` function return `None` and in your for loop, you do not have to increment `i`, because it is incremented automatically

you can try:

```
def printing(n):

  for i in range(n):
    print('next')
    print(i)


printing(4)
```

output:

```
next
0
next
1
next
2
next
3
```